# How are user accounts being sync'd without a UPSA

Tags: user-profile-service

I have a 2013 farm with no user profile service application configured, the purpose of the farm is to run a single application which lives on top of SharePoint and administers insurance claims.  One user profile out of about 500 has been imported as DOMAIN\samaccountname instead of being a proper profile showing active directory details such as the user's job title and resolving in the application to a proper Firstname Lastname in the app. Ordinarily I'd use purge non-imported objects to kill this and re-run UPSA sync, but there's no application configured - how are these accounts getting into SharePoint in the absence of a UPSA and what do I do when one hasn't done it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, users are added to the hidden User Information List the first time they access the site (any site in the site collection - each site collection has its own User Information List and there is only one per site collection).

If the user accessing the site is not already in the User Information List, it is added to it and any data gathered from AD is stored in the columns in the list for the new user object (can't say for sure if all columns are actually fetched from AD). After this has happened, I don't think this information is ever updated or changed by SharePoint.

I guess there are two ways to fix invalid data in User Information List:

- Edit it manually in the standard SharePoint form
- Delete the user and have it populated automatically the next time the user accesses a site in the site collection (can't say for sure if this is safe/possible regarding any existing column values in the site collection that may reference the user - like "Created By")

You access the User Information List with a URL similar to:

http://companyweb/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0

where you'll be able to edit and delete users.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was able to delete the user from the standard people page and re-add them, waiting for the people picker to resolve their correct information from AD.